# Angular factory access method within factory with this. and I get undefined function

Tags: angularjs, factory, self

Hi everyone I am having some issues with an angular factory.  Trying to call a function in my controller from the factory, this function calls another function within the same factory with `this`. but I always get the console "error undefined is not a function"

```
angular.module('psJwtApp').factory('authToken', function ($window) {
  var storage = $window.localStorage;
  var cachedToken;
  return {
    setToken: function(token){
      cachedToken = token;
      storage.setItem('userToken', token);
    },
    getToken: function(){
      if(!cachedToken) 
        {cachedToken = storage.getItem('userToken');}

        return cachedToken; 
    },
    isAuthenticated: function() {
      return !!self.getToken();

    }
  };
});
```

Then I call it in my angular controller:

```
angular.module('psJwtApp').controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, authToken) {
  $scope.isAuthenticated = authToken.isAuthenticated; 
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried calling the `getToken` as `this`, as `self`, as `authToken.getToken`.  Nothing.  if I console out `authToken.getToken` I get `undefined`.  Any Ideas what could be going on?

Comment: where is `var self=this`? maybe you forgot that?

Comment: I think one of the problems is that you are missing the `()` at the end of the method call: `$scope.isAuthenticated = authToken.isAuthenticated();`.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira thanks for the suggestion, when I declare it as authToken.isAuthenticated(); i still get undefined is not a function.

Comment: @anvarik sorry var self=this also gives me undefined function. If I declare it on my ctrl as authToken.isAuthenticated(); chrome points the error to the controller.  If I declare  as authToken.isAuthenticated and do this.IsAuthenticated then chrome points to the actual factory file and the line where I am calling this.isAuthenticated or self..isAuthenticated.  Even after setting var self to this

Comment: @jsrosas you should be able to use `this.getToken` no need for self, and post your complete code

Comment: @anvarik thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried that and still get undefined. authtoken factory is called in my headerctrl which is the controller for a html view which calls it as ng-if="isAuthenticated()".

Comment: I should mention that the token is being set by an api, and it is stored in the localstorage.  It is visible from chrome inspect.

Comment: if you add `console.log(this);` before `return !!self.getToken();`, what is the output at the console? You should not be using `self` for sure, since it really is `undefined` (unless defined by some code you have not provided). But you mentioned that `this.getToken()` also failed.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira thanks a lot for your suggestion.  I got the following :ChildScope {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array[3], $$listeners: Object…}$$ChildScope: null$$childHead: null$$childTail: null$$listenerCount: Object$$listeners: Object$$nextSibling: null$$prevSibling: null$$watchers: Array[3]$id: 4$parent: ChildScopeisAuthenticated: function () {__proto__: ChildScope

Comment: I also tried to do consolo log from the original getToken function and it didn't even call that.  I dont think I missed any brackets but it seems getToken: function(){},  is not being recognized as a function.  I cant figure out why its not.

Answer (score 3):

Finally resolved this issue by declaring all functions inside an object and returning that object. Then simple call authToken.getToken and all works well in my world!

```
angular.module('psJwtApp').factory('authToken', function ($window) {
var storage = $window.localStorage;
var cachedToken;
var userToken = 'userToken';
var authToken = {
    setToken: function(token){
      cachedToken = token;
      storage.setItem( userToken, token);
    },
    getToken: function(){
      if(!cachedToken) 
        {cachedToken = storage.getItem(userToken)};
        return cachedToken; 
    },
    isAuthenticated: function() {
      return !!authToken.getToken();
    },
    removeToken: function() {
      cachedToken = null;
      storage.removeItem(userToken);
    }
  };
  return authToken;
```

});